# Objective C - Difference between Class and Object

Tags: class, object, methods, instance

I am reading a book about Objective C programming and the first 80 pages was the basics of C.

And then at the first pages about Objective C they write about Classes and Objects And Instances etc.
And i can't tell what is a class and what is an object and what is an instance and what is a method?

and i repeat this is Objective C. :)

Can some expert please give me some examples and easy explanations how to tell the difference what each of them is?

There is a lot of similar questions on these forums i can see, but i was not able to find any related to Objective C.

PS: I have no prior experience with Objective C, i am completely new, i know the basics of C, and also some C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can think a class as a data type like an `Integer`.

An object is an instance of class.

Many instances can exist of the same class.

For example, the numbers 1, 2, -1, 0 are all objects of the class `Integer`.

Here is an example:

To define a class we create a blueprint for a class:

```
@interface Box : NSObject
{
    double length;   // Length of a box
    double breadth;  // Breadth of a box
}
```

And some other stuff around for `init` method (not mentioned here).

Next, we create two different instances / object of class `Box`:

```
Box box1 = [[Box alloc]init]; // Create box1 object of type Box

Box box2 = [[Box alloc]init]; // Create box2 object of type Box
```

Comment: I just get confused when there is classes called "MyOwnClass" how can i tell what an object from that class is?
It makes more sense when the class is Integer, i know what an integer is hehe

Comment: so, box1 and box2 are of type Box, so the class 'Box' is actually some kind of data type?
and is instance / objects not the same thing then?

Comment: I have added some code to explain to you how a data type is created by using `@interface`. When we include header files to use some classes these declarations exist in these files.

Comment: @Jacob: Yes, and It has two properties (length and breadth). However, through inheritance it gets any information NSObject has. But this is another OOP idea. Also, is supposed to have an `init' method which is called after the allocation of box1 and box2, but I didn't add the code for it. You can find examples on the Internet.

Comment: Okay an example from my book is: 
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
is NSDate then a class and *now is a object?

Comment: Jacob: Not exactly. Here, you are calling the "class method" `date` from NSDate class which is different from "object methods". This method creates an object and returns only the pointer to `now` variable. The `now` variable contains an address which points to a memory address where the created object exists.

Comment: NSDate is a class defined or declared in foundation framework right?
and it has a method (which is alot like a function i read) called date 
which returns a value which is current date right? or am i completely off track here?

Comment: And is the object then the return value of date method / function which is current date?

Comment: Yes, exactly the current date.

Comment: Okay what is an instance of a class?

Comment: You should definitely, read an OOP book in order to learn some basics.